# Terraform one policy to multiple IAM roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to attach an existing IAM policy to multiple IAM roles that have the same naming convention, I am trying it with below terraform files but it's not working.

**vars.tf**

```
variable "aws_iam_role_names" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["name1", "name2", "name3"]
}
```

**main.tf**

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "iam-role" {
role = "${var.aws_iam_role_names[count.index]}-iam-role"
policy_arn = var.some_policy_arn
}
```

My goal here is to use a single resource block and attach some_policy_arn to the roles name1-iam-role, name2-iam-role, name3-iam-role and whichever role names I add to the variables in the future.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [count](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/count):

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "iam-role" {
  count = length(var.aws_iam_role_names)
  role = "${var.aws_iam_role_names[count.index]}-iam-role"
  policy_arn = var.some_policy_arn
}
```

for [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each):

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "iam-role" {
  for_each = toset(var.aws_iam_role_names)
  role = "${each.key}-iam-role"
  policy_arn = var.some_policy_arn
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I believe I can apply the same logic to create multiple policies as well like user1-policy, user2-policy and user3-policy. Is there anyway we can map those policies to the respective roles and attach them?

Comment: @John I think for your new issue, a new question with relevant code examples would be better.